# HttpContext.Session empty after app is published on Service Fabric cluster

Tags: azure, session, caching, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

The application uses `OAuth2 flow` to login on the users' O365 accounts and to store the returned access tokens in the session variable. The following code is used to store the tokens:

```
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
    Request.Query["code"],                                         
    loginRedirectUri,                                               
    new ClientCredential(ConfigSettings.ClientId, ConfigSettings.ClientSecret), 
    ConfigSettings.O365UnifiedAPIResource);

var authResultEWS = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
    Request.Query["code"],                                         
    loginRedirectUri,                                               
    new ClientCredential(ConfigSettings.ClientId, ConfigSettings.ClientSecret), 
    ConfigSettings.EWSAPIResource);

HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeys.Login.AccessToken, authResult.AccessToken);
HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeys.Login.EWSAccessToken, authResultEWS.AccessToken);
```

And here is how we get the tokens back in our controllers:

```
private string GetSessionValue(string key)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue(key, out buffer);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
}
```

This soluton works on a local 5 nodes cluster but once published on an Azure 3 node cluster, the `Session` does not seem to work.

I used remote debugging and the access tokens are correctly added but once I call `GetSessionValue`, `HttpContext.Session` contains 0 key.

If using `HttpContext.Session` is a bad idea for distributed architectures like SF, what would be a good replacement solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Session data is scoped to the node it runs on. In order to have a highly available (distributed) solution, you'd need to take the data and replicate it to other nodes.

Service Fabric Reliable [Stateful Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-introduction/) and [Actors](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction/) have such  mechanisms built in. You could use one of those to cache your (protected) access tokens. (and optionally serve as a gateway to O365)